# Selenium - How to click on this span?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried using cssSelector and xpath. I can't use `class=chips__text` as it is not unique. How can I click on the span with text `Nou`?

```
<ul id="targetparam17" class="chipschoice fleft">
   <li class="hidden">
      <a href="#" class="is-selected">
         <span class="chips__text">Alege</span>
         <span class="value"></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a href="#" class="">
         <span class="chips__text">Utilizat</span>
         <span class="value">used</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a href="#" class="">
         <span class="chips__text">Nou</span>
         <span class="value">new</span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the element with respect to the desired text i.e. "Nou" and then click on it. xpath for it is `//span[text()='Nou']`. In case if you with to use different texts to click on different spans, you can manipulate the xpath using string manipulation techniques. Hope it helps :)

Comment: elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Nou']")) not working..

Comment: Try to find the element and click on it. For eg. `WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Nou']")).click();` or `WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Nou']")); ele.click();`

Comment: @AndreiCraciun ElementClickInterceptedException Indicates that a click could not be properly executed because the target element was obscured in some way. You should first make sure it isDisplayed() and isEnabled().

Answer (score 0):

`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` means to selenium to be clickable is that it is visible & enabled. [See Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c982edfbd3eed3ffb9666c4f3e9df7c004834c22/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L632)

So you should check whether webElement isDisplayed() & isEnabled().

Or alternatively you can use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement)`

Answer (score 0):

I've used //span[contains(.,'Nou')] and it works perfectly

Comment: In that case, this `//span[text()='Nou']` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='targetparam17']//li//a//span[contains(.,'Nou')")
```